# Luxrender - Mixing materials using layer weight

Tags: rendering, materials

Please can someone explain how to mix materials based on viewing angle in luxrender in a similar way to Cycles which uses the layer weight node. I would like to be able to combine several materials with the mix defined by the angle of the camera to the objects surface. Unfortunately Luxrender doesn't seem to have a layer weight node and I can't get the fresnel nodes to work to control a mix material.

Thanks

Comment: It is better to direct questions about Luxrender and the blender addon, to the luxrender website. http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/index

The community is quite strong and active. http://www.luxrender.net/forum/ and has a materials help section.